# Restful Webservices javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean itemController

Tags: web-services, rest, jpa, curl, ejb-3.1

I'm trying out an Jax-RS example that involves EJB+JPA+JSF. i can normally run the example but when i remove the comments below in Stateless EJB bean;

```
// @Context
//    private UriInfo uriInfo;

/*   @POST
    @Path("book")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJaxbBook(JAXBElement<Book> bookJaxb) {
        Book book = bookJaxb.getValue();
        book.setIsbn(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
        em.persist(book);
        em.flush(); // to get the id
        URI bookUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(book.getId().toString()).build();
        Response resp = Response.created(bookUri).build();
        logger.fine("ItemEJB.createJaxbBook():" + resp.toString());
        return resp;
    } */
```

when i run the example with uncommented version, i get error so that ;

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean itemController

root cause

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean itemController

root cause

com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method private void org.beginningee6.training.web.ItemController.initList()

root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method private void org.beginningee6.training.web.ItemController.initList()

root cause

java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB

root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB

root cause

javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1

When i insert a record to database with curl ;

curl -X POST --data-binary "{ \"title\":\"book333\", \"price\":\"24.0\", \"description\":\"3rd Scifi IT book\", \"illustrations\":\"false\", \"isbn\":\"134-234\", \"nbOfPage\":\"241\" }" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/Lab17-REST/rs/items/book

then refresh the page, project is normally running. How can i candle this issue.

Comment: i solved the problem like below
    @Path("book")  @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJaxbBook(JAXBElement<Book> bookJaxb,@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        Book book = bookJaxb.getValue();
        book.setIsbn(numberGenerator.generateNumber());
        em.persist(book);
        em.flush(); // to get the id
        URI bookUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(book.getId().toString()).build();
        Response resp = Response.created(bookUri).build();
        logger.fine("ItemEJB.createJaxbBook():" + resp.toString());
        return resp;
    }